# Significance of chariots of Jagannath Rath Yatra?

Tags: vishnu, gods, festivals

Three beautiful chariots are used in Rath Yatra festival for three persisting deities. What are the significance of the chariots of Rath Yatra ?

Answer (score 1):

Rath Yatra is not only celebrated in India, but this auspicious festival celebrated all over the world by Lord Jagannath followers.

The Name of the three chariots of RATH YATRA

1. Nandighosha :- Chariot of Lord Jagannath
2. Padmadhwaja/ Devadalana :- Chariot of Mata Subhadra
3. Taladhwaja :- Chariot of Balabhadra

**Goddess Subhadra’s Chariot: Padmadhwaja/ Devadalana**

- the smallest of the chariots
- canopy color : black and red
- 4 horses of red color
- Height : 43 feet
- No. of wheels : 12
- Flag : Nadambika
- The guardian deity of the chariot : Jayadurga and the charioteer is known as Arjuna
- The face of the Chariot : Bhakti Sumedha
- The weapons : Padma & Kalhar
- 9 Deities present on the chariot :  Chandi, Chamunda, Ugratara, Vanadurga, Shulidurga, Varahi, Shyama Kali, Mangala and Bimala.

**Lord Balabhadra’s Chariot: Taladhwaja**

- canopy color : green and red
- 4 horses of black color
- Height : 44 feet
- No. of wheels : 14
- Flag : Unnani
- Emblem: Sudarshana Chakra
- The guardian deity of the chariot : Vasudev and the charioteer is known as Matali
- The face of the Chariot : Ketu Bhadra
- The weapons : Hala & Musala
- 9 Deities present on the chariot :  Ganesha, Kartikeya, Sarvamangala, Pralambari, Halayudha, Mrutyunjaya, Natamvara, Mukteshwar & Sheshadeva

**Lord Jagannath’s Chariot: Nandighosha**

- Largest among all chariots.
- canopy color : yellow and red
- 4 horses of white color
- Height : 45 feet
- No. of wheels : 16
- Flag : Trailokyamohini
- Emblem: Sudarshana Chakra
- The guardian deity of the chariot : Garuda and the charioteer is known as Daruka
- The face of the Chariot : Nandi Mukha
- The weapons : Sankha & Chakra
- 9 Deities present on the chariot :  Varaha, Govardhana, Krushna, Nrusimgha, Rama, Narayana, Trivikrama, Hanuman, and Rudra.

Similar information can be found in the temple website [here](http://jagannath.nic.in/?q=node/487) and also in [this](http://www.jagannathdham.in/rath-yatra-festival/details-of-rath-yatra-chariots/) blog.

Comment: You can link to your own blog but upto a limit. Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) posts on meta.SE.